# Google Sheets Detect Text and Concatenate or Join

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lCgHPPXML5Ll9XsrMPXmNnHOEQO0RZP-aWSbMtiCfg4/edit?usp=sharing

My goal here is for sheet 3-5 Checklist to look through Grade 5 and Grade 4 and detect all instances of specific text then return the project name. For example:

C2 on 3-5 Checklist should be searching the sheets Grade 5 and Grade 4 for all instances of the text in B2. C2 should find all these from both the Grade 5 sheet and the Grade 4 sheet:
"5th ELA:  Research Based Argument,
5th Robot Week,
5th Typing Program,
5th ELA: Poetry,
5th Science: Web of Life,
4th Typing Curriculum"

The goal is that cells in C & E are using B & D as reference so that if we add a project on the 4th or 5th grade sheets and say a project fits a standard that project will quickly show up on the Checklist sheet.

The real project is bigger but I figure if someone can help me get the basics down I'll be able to apply it larger.

Thank you,

Comment: I think there's a step to take before you try to do what you've asked for.  See the new tab called DB_Idea.  There is a single dynamic formula creating that database that is reading from both 4th and 5th grade.  using that tab as a reference, i think it will be much easier to write the formulas you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what MattKing has recommended in the comments, you can use the sheet DB_Idea and just filter the data there (resulting to a more simple filtering).

I tried and compared the result and the only difference is that using DB_Idea sheet includes what grade the project is but removing it via `regexreplace` should be doable.

#### Formula (C2):

```
=ifna(regexreplace(join(char(10),filter(DB_Idea!$B$2:$B,DB_Idea!$A$2:$A=B2)), "Grade \d+: ", ""), "")
```

#### Output:

[image: output]